# "Conditional" Join Based on Field Value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

The site I'm working on has 3 different types of users: admin, applicants, reviewers. Each of these groups will have some basic info that will need to be stored (name, id, email, etc) as well as some data that is unique to each. I have created a `users` table as well as a table for each of the specific groups to store their unique data.

- users: id, f_name, l_name, email, user_type
- users_admin: id, user_id, office, emp_id
- users_applicant: id, user_id, dob, address
- users_reviewer: id, user_id, active_status, address, phone

If a user with `user_type` of "1" (applicant) logs in I will need to `JOIN` to the `users_applicants` table to retrieve their full record. I tried using a `UNION` but my tables have vastly different columns.

Is there a way to, based on a user's type, write a conditional query that will `JOIN` to the correct table? Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Thank's in advance for your help!

Comment: Why does this have to happen in SQL and not PHP? What have you already tried?

Comment: Since you'll have to deal with 3 distinct groups of columns at the outset why not have 3 distinct queries?

Comment: @DanMan I guess that's one thing I was wondering as well. Would it be bad practice to query to get the user's type, and then with PHP determine the JOIN to use?

Comment: @DanMan is correct below, if you go with TPT here, dump the table specific keys and the Id key from the base table is the only one you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the end your tables are already flawed. Why even have a table for each type? Why not put all those fields into the `users` table, or maybe a `user_details` table (if you really want an extra table for non-general data fields)? Currently, you're actually creating 4 independent user tables from a relational point of view.

So why do the type-tables have a surrogate key? Why isn't the `user_id` already the (only) primary key?

If you changed that, all you would need is the user id to retrieve the data you want, and you've already got that (or you wouldn't even be able to retrieve the user type).

Comment: I wouldn't have a problem using one users table. Given that each user type requires different values this would result in many empty fields though, which I thought was something to avoid. Is this not the case?

Comment: That's true, but not as bad as running a complicated query across multiple tables. As long as those empty columns don't have to be NULL-able - no big deal.

Comment: @Vecta Table per type is a valid DB structure, not sure there is enough information to determine if it is being used appropriately here, but it is very useful in many situations. It is much easier when using an ORM and don't have to worry about this part of it though.

Comment: @Matthew: Maybe, but relating entries through anything but foreign keys is definately bad design. So if he wanted to keep the tables as is, he'd need at least a `users_types` table, as raheel shan suggested.

Comment: @DanMan Agreed - suggested something similar in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I'll combine my tables per your suggestion.

Comment: @Vecta just for the record, you design is not incorrect in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Either you do it programmatically, or you can do this with a series of `CASE`s and `LEFT JOIN`s.

For simplicity's sake let's do this with a table `users` where you can have a user of type 1 (normal user), 2 (power user) or 3 (administrator). Normal users have an email but no telephone, power users have an address and a field dubbed "superpower", and administrators have a telephone number and nothing else.

Since you want to use the same `SELECT` for all, of course you need to place all these in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT user.id, user.type, email, address, superpower, telephone
```

and you will then need to `LEFT JOIN` to recover these

```
FROM user
LEFT JOIN users_data ON (user.id = users_data.user_id)
LEFT JOIN power_data ON (user.id = power_data.user_id)
LEFT JOIN admin_info ON (user.id = admin_info.user_id)
```

Now the "unused" fields will be `NULL`, but you can supply defaults:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN user.type = 0 THEN email ELSE 'nobody@nowhere.com' END AS email,
    CASE WHEN user.type = 1 OR user.type = 2 THEN ... ELSE ... END as whatever,
    ...
```

Specific `WHERE` conditions you can put in the `JOIN` itself, e.g. if you only want administrators from the J sector, you can use

```
LEFT JOIN admin_info ON (user.id = admin_info.user_id AND admin_info.sector = 'J')
```

The total query time should not be too bad, seeing as most of the `JOIN`s will return little (and, if you specify a user ID, they will actually return *nothing* very quickly).

You could also do the same using a `UNION`, which would be even faster:

```
SELECT user.id, 'default' AS email, 'othermissingfield' AS missingfieldinthistable,
  ... FROM user JOIN user_data ON (user.id = user_data.user_id)
  WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT user.id, email, 'othermissingfield' AS missingfieldinthistable,
  ... FROM user JOIN power_data ON (user.id = power_data.user_id)
  WHERE ...
UNION
  ...
```

Now, if you specify the user ID, all queries except one will fail very fast. Each query has the same `WHERE` repeated plus any table-specific conditions. The `UNION` version is less maintainable (unless you generate it programmatically), but ought to be marginally faster.

In all cases, you'll be well advised in keeping updated indexes on the appropriate fields.

Answer (score 1):

Instead i will suggest you reconstruct you tables structure like this.

Create a table

```
users_types : 
id 
type
```

Then create another table users with a foreign key

```
users :     
id 
f_name 
l_name 
email 
office 
emp_id 
dob 
address 
active_status 
phone 
users_types_id
```

And now when you need to insert data insert null in the fields which are not required for a particular user. And you can simply fetch records on the basis  of id. Also using left join will give you the name of user type.

Comment: The `users_types` table would only be required if users could have more than one type. And even then you might get away with a SET() column.